# « De leur amour plus bleu que le ciel autour » : la couleur de l'amour ?

Tags: sens, adjectifs, paroles-de-chanson, comparatifs

Dans la [chanson](https://youtu.be/GV85QI6NjM0) [*Petite Marie*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petite_Marie) de Francis Cabrel on trouve les paroles suivantes (je souligne) :

> *Je viens du ciel et les étoiles entre elles
>  Ne parlent que de toi
>  D'un musicien qui fait jouer ses mains
>  Sur un morceau de bois
>  De
> leur amour plus **bleu** que le ciel autour*

Le comparatif de supériorité « plus bleu que le ciel autour », ça évoque le haut degré de quoi au juste ? La *sentimentalité*, l'*intensité*, la *pureté*, la *noblesse*, la *stupéfaction*, la *profondeur* ; est-ce un des sens de [*bleu*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/bleu), ou autre chose, est-ce un procédé sémantique ou syntaxique : comment ça teinte l'amour ?

Comment: [Interpétation plus récente](https://youtu.be/s8aodSP4qQU?t=191)... :)

Comment: « De leur *amour* plus *bleu* que le *ciel* autour ». Le rapprochement avec *ciel* donne un sens divin au mot *bleu*, une sorte d'*amour* que les grands mystiques portent à l'indicible, apparemment relié au *cœur* (rouge passionnel) mais en fait au ***chœur*** ensemble de voix harmonieuses, espace vibrant d'une église que l'on retrouve en haut des poumons, au-dessus du *cœur*, dans le *corps* humain et juste en dessous de la *voix qui chante* (zone d'un chakra de couleur bleue).

Comment: C'est de la poésie!

Answer (score 2):

Ça évoque le haut degré de la pureté, quand le ciel est bleu on dit qu'il est pur. Donc l'amour est plus pur que le ciel.

Answer (score 0):

Bien avant l'époque de Cabrel, a été écrite une chanson dont le titre était « *L'amour est bleu* » ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27amour_est_bleu)). C'est « une chanson française, dont l'air a été composé par André Popp et les paroles ont été écrites par Pierre Cour en 1967 ». Cabrel, dont la période d'activité ne débute qu'en 1974, était un musicien intéressé par le  pop rock et le  blues ([Cabrel](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Cabrel)).

Here are the words. ([réf.](http://www.diggiloo.net/?1967lu))

L'amour est bleu

Doux, doux, l'amour est doux
Douce est ma vie, ma vie dans tes bras
Doux, doux, l'amour est doux
Douce est ma vie, ma vie près de toi

Bleu, bleu, l'amour est bleu
Berce mon cœur, mon cœur amoureux
Bleu, bleu, l'amour est bleu
Bleu comme le ciel qui joue dans tes yeux

Comme l'eau, comme l'eau qui court
Moi, mon cœur court après ton amour

Gris, gris, l'amour est gris
Pleure mon cœur lorsque tu t'en vas
Gris, gris, le ciel est gris
Tombe la pluie quand tu n'es plus là

Le vent, le vent gémit
Pleure le vent lorsque tu t'en vas  ay
Le vent, le vent maudit
Pleure mon cœur quand tu n'es plus là

Comme l'eau, comme l'eau qui court
Moi, mon cœur court après ton amour

Bleu, bleu, l'amour est bleu
Le ciel est bleu lorsque tu reviens
Bleu, bleu, l'amour est bleu
L'amour est bleu quand tu prends ma main

Fou, fou, l'amour est fou
Fou comme toi et fou comme moi
Bleu, bleu, l'amour est bleu
L'amour est bleu quand je suis à toi
L'amour est bleu quand je suis à toi

L'arrangement des couplets montre que le bleu  est associé à la douceur de l'amour et non pas à la tristesse comme on pourrait l'escompter et que c'est le gris qui est associé à la tristesse de l'amour. La comparaison avec le ciel assure qu'il ne s'agit pas des connotations négatives associées avec le bleu ([réf.](https://mon.astrocenter.fr/voyance/mag/signification-couleur-bleue)), la passivité, la mélancholie, la dépression.

Dans la chanson à Cabrel, il y a donc de très fortes chances d'une association de « bleu » avec la douceur de l'amour, et non pas avec des notions de sentimentalité, intensité, pureté, etc.

Comment: Note qu'en Belgique, "être bleu de quelqu'un" signifie en être éperdument amoureux.

Comment: « Bleu comme le ciel qui joue dans tes yeux » ; ça pourrait n'être qu'une métonymie ici, elle a peut-être les yeux bleus ?

Comment: @LaurentS. J'admire cette adéquation linguistique, peut-être qu'en France aussi ça participe de ce sens-là ? Cabrel est du sud-ouest.

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie — Non, c'est leur amour qui est azur (le bleu des poètes qui enveloppe l'Éther) pas leurs iris.